# COCOS2D-X: scale sprite

Tags: scale, cocos2d-x

I want to set scale for a sprite by height of original image.
And then the width of that sprite will follow by original ratio of that image.
How can i do that.
Thank for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCSprite has a member function

```
virtual void setScale(float scale)
```

Reference:[setScale](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0alpha0/d8/de9/group__sprite__nodes.html#gaba8cb6b2364f18f8b8cb2abc9fe6828f)

Just create a sprite, and call this function.

```
CCSprite* bg = CCSprite::create("background.png");
this->addChild(bg,0);
bg->setScale(2.0);
```

bg sprite will be twice bigger than the origin one.

Comment: thanks, what effect if any does this have on the original image? I want to build my resources at high resolution then scale them down based on actual device resolution to save RAM.

Answer (score 0):

use setScale function of CCSprite e.g -

```
CCSprite *Sprite   =   CCSprite::create(WHEEL_SPRITE);
Sprite->setScale(DIRECTOR_VISIBLE_HEIGHT*0.65/Sprite->getContentSize().height);
Sprite->setPosition(ccp(DIRECTOR_VISIBLE_WIDTH/2, DIRECTOR_VISIBLE_HEIGHT/2));
this->addChild(Sprite);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second line? You're taking 65% of the visible height and dividing it by the height of the sprite, but why?

Answer (score -1):

You can scale by width or height only with: `sprite->setScaleX()` and `sprite->setScaleY()`