# C++ - How to play animation in opposite direction Cocos2DX

Tags: c++, animation, cocos2d-x, sprite, cocos2d-x-3.0

I got a png like this

[image]

I also got this segment of code

```
SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("walk.plist", "walk.png");
Vector<SpriteFrame*> animFrames;
animFrames.reserve(8);
char spriteFrameByName[MAX_WORD] = { 0 };

for (int index = 1; index <= 8; index++)
{

    sprintf(spriteFrameByName, "%d.png", index);

    auto frame = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->getSpriteFrameByName(spriteFrameByName);

    animFrames.pushBack(frame);
}
Animation* animation = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames, time);
sprite->runAction(Animate::create(animation));
```

Now I want to horizontally flip this animation. Something looks like this

[image]

Not to create another png file, is there a way to this in C++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation* animation = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames, time);

sprite->runAction(Animate::create(animation));

sprite->setFlipX(true)

Answer (score 1):

Horizontally flipping an image is equal to scaling the x-axis of that image minus 1. I am not familiar with Cocos2DX, but multiplying the x scale of your image by -1 will horizontally flip it for you.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22370186/4584421) might help you with scaling:

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if flip function handles the rotation of the object you want to flip. I believe that it only changes the texture's direction. Which may end up making things a bit more complex down the road if you ever need to compute which direction is your character is facing in your game world.

You can rotate the entire sprite on Y axis. by doing so, It will make sure that everything facing in right direction and not just the texture. Following code provides the same visual by rotating entire sprite.

```
sprite->setRotation3D(Vec3(0, 180, 0));
```